# How to check values against the DB when using the pre-save hook?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

On a User schema, I'd like to check if the specified email already exists for the specified shop, before saving.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _shop: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Shop',
        required: true
    },
    email: String,
    //...
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next();
    // How to do use the static method isThatEmailFreeForThisShop here?
});

UserSchema.statics.isThatEmailFreeForThisShop = function(email, shop_id, cb) {
    this.find({email: email, _shop: shop_id}, function(err, users) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

There could be different users with the same email as long as they are from different shops.
I do not know how to use the static method in the pre-save hook...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a User Model instance somewhere (I'll call it `User`):

```
var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

So, the `isThatEmailFreeForThisShop` function is available on the `User` model:

```
User.isThatEmailFreeForThisShop(...)
```

From your save hook:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next();
    User.isThatEmailFreeForThisShop(this.email, this._shop, 
        function(err, result) {
            if (result) { // found
               // do something
               return next({ error: "duplicate found" });
            }
            return next();
    });
});
```

You may also want to switch to using the pre-`validate` rather than `save`.

I'd expect in your function, `isThatEmailFreeForThisShop` that you'd call the `cb` parameter when the results have been "found".

You probably would use `findOne` ([reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)) rather than `find`. Given that there's still a race condition, you'd want to [add an index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) as a compound index `email` and `shop_id` and set the `unique` attribute to true to prevent duplicates from sneaking in (then, you'll need to handle the fact that a `save` on a model instance may throw an error.)

```
UserSchema.statics.isThatEmailFreeForThisShop = function(email, shop_id, cb) {
    this.findOne({email: email, _shop: shop_id}, function(err, user) {
        // ...
        cb(err, user != null);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, that was easier than expected! Thank you for this insightful reply! I'm not sure why should I set the unique attribute though?

Comment: If you want the combo of email & shop to be a unique pair. (That was what it seemed like you were doing in the call to `find`).